# How can I list available input devices with haxe?

Tags: keyboard, mouse, haxe, joystick, input-devices

I would like to list all the input devices available when I launch an application, but I can't find a way to do that in the API.

How can I get a list of available keyboards, mice, gamepads, touch screens, accelerometers...

Answer (score 1):

Haxe is a programming language that compiles to other languages. There are projects that use the compiled haxe code to deploy to different runtimes. For example the NME framework compiles to neko, html5, flash, mobile etc. So your question doesn't really make the strictest sense.

I doubt there is an api for getting a list of the available input devices in nme as generally it will be evident. You could however go through the api one input at a time to test if its available or working I guess.

Do you have a special need for this? generally people usually use compiler conditionals to determine these things eg;

```
#if mobile
//your touch input code
#elseif desktop
//your mouse / keyboard code
#end
```

Comment: Yes, I need to display multiple items on the "player select your side" screen depending on the number of keyboard/mouse and game pads connected (android, mac, windows...).

Comment: I have never heard of a game using multiple keyboard/mouse???maybe you should start off with a more simple game, if you start to learn nme it does support multiple joysticks.

Comment: There are multiple examples through history, Settlers for example had split screen multiplayer with multiple mice support.

Comment: Ok I have never seen a pc game that uses multiple mice but it turns out you are correct, thanks http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/24046/is-it-possible-to-detect-two-different-mice-at-the-same-time-and-have-their-mov. However I am not aware of any haxe library supporting this as it looks like an "extension" to the os. Your best bet is to make a feature request or fork nme or another haxe project yourself, check out nme.io.

Answer (score 1):

There is exist *Joystick API* in OpenFL for gamepads.

> Each event has an “device” property, which specifies which input device the event is coming from. In this way, you can support multiple joysticks or (probably) gamepads in one game.

http://www.joshuagranick.com/blog/?p=692